# Weird text protrusions

Tags: text-object

I have this weird text issue it happens randomly where some text objects will stretch out endlessly from one point of the text. The text has not been converted to mesh or anything they are just parented and the parents have some animations on them. The protrusions go away if I delete and undo or change a text setting but I’ve had this problem for a while and I don’t know why it’s happening. Im using the font Open_Sans and not the default font. I’m also in EEVEE. Please help so I can stop this from happening in the future, thanks.

These images show the problem as you can there are strange protrusions coming out of those text objects how can I prevent this from happening?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please foramt your pictures properly so they are easier to look at. And it would also be helpful to share your blendfile over blendexchange, https://blend-exchange.com/ Thank you